# Deployment pipe in DevOps succeeds but app is not executing after switch to Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We made a deployment pipe and made it work on a Win machine. Then, we decided to attempt deploying it on Linux and created a new app service with Linux machine etc. Trying to reuse the previously working pipe, we made a few adaptations.

Partly, `--runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64` (in the build step). Also, replacing the deployment step with the following.

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'se-tyr-aux-az-con'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'app-aux-recorder'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|7.0'
    StartupCommand: 'dotnet run'
```

Now, the content of the YAML is as follows.

```
pool:
   vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  project: '**/*.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(project)'
    arguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:target=package 
      /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
      /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'se-tyr-aux-az-con'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'app-aux-recorder'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|7.0'
    StartupCommand: 'dotnet run'
```

Each step reports green success. The application gets the default "some good stuff coming soon" page. However, swagger endpoint doesn't work nor does the controller method (status code 404 Not Found).

We're not sure if the application is running but fails to serve the request or if it's not been properly deployed. Checking the console (accessible during the deployment time), I can see a bunch of DLL's in the *wwwroot* directory's subfolders, including a file called *Api* (no file extension) that corresponds to the project's name.

Now sure how to investigate further. The documentation on YAMLs for Azure leaves a bit to ask and googling it gave me not much leads. We've used mostly [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive) and linked to it [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). They aren't of the highest quality.

Setting `vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'` produced an error about the deployment not being able to find IIS instance, which suggests that we somehow made Azure think that we're targeting Windows with our deployment. However, I fail to see where we do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you skipped some properties at the build step. I'm not familiar using this kind of arguments. Probably you need to pass the result of the build process to the deploy step, and, at the publish process, specify what files have to be deployed to you linux webapp.

This is the simplest way to achive it:

[Deploy a .Net app (to an Azure WebApp)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#deploy-a-net-app)

```
    steps:
    - script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
      displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: true
    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '<Azure service connection>'
        appType: 'webAppLinux'
        appName: '<Name of web app>'
        package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

As I like things clear, I would suggest to make it more explicit but at the same time more clear just doing a first and simple build step, and then a publish one to set the publish result (zip file) to a specific directory. Then, catch that zip within the AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 step. Here, in this final step, you should use the zip result that is going to be used in the task.

This solution combines this steps:

[Build project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive#build-your-project)

[Publish project (skip the PublishPipelineArtifact task)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#deploy-a-net-app)

[Deploy to Azure webApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#deploy-to-multiple-web-apps)

Here goes an example:

```
    variables:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    project: '**/*.csproj'
    buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    azureSubscription: 'se-tyr-aux-az-con'
    webAppName: 'app-aux-recorder'
    
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: build
        projects: '$(project)'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
        
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        projects: '$(project)'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) -r ubuntu.16.04-x64 --self-contained true --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        #this is equivalent to /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
        zipAfterPublish: true
        
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      displayName: Api
      inputs:
        ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
        appType: 'Web App on Linux'
        WebAppName: '$(webAppName)'
        packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
        # $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) is the path where de publish task set the zip
```

In other hand, you can create a multi-stage pipeline to deploy the Windows and linux app simultaniously.

This solution is an approach of the offical documentation:

[Deploy to multiple web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#deploy-to-multiple-web-apps)

Something similar to this:

```
    stages: 
    - stage: BuildIt
      jobs:
      - job: BuildTheCode
        pool:
            vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
        variables:
            solution: '**/*.sln'
            project: '**/*.csproj'
            buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
            buildConfiguration: 'Release'
        steps:
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: 'Build'
          inputs:
            command: build
            projects: '$(project)'
            arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
            
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: 'Publish'
          inputs:
            command: publish
            projects: '**/*.csproj'
            arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            #this is equivalent to /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
            zipAfterPublish: true
        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          inputs:
            targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
            artifactName: '<artifact-name>'

    - stage: Deployment
      jobs: 
        - job: Publish to Windows
            variables:
                azureSubscription: 'se-tyr-aux-az-con'
                webAppName: '<your-windows-webapp-name>'
            steps: 
            # download the artifact from the previous job
            - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
              inputs:
                source: 'current'
                artifact: 'drop'
                path: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment
                inputs:
                    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
                    appType: 'webApp' #you can skip this, default value is webApp 
                    WebAppName: '$(webAppName)'
                    package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.zip'
        - job: Publish to Linux
            variables:
                azureSubscription: 'se-tyr-aux-az-con'
                webAppName: '<your-linux-webapp-name>'
            steps: 
            - download: 'current'
                artifact: '<artifact-name>'
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment
                inputs:
                    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
                    appType: 'webAppLinux'
                    WebAppName: '$(webAppName)'
                    packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.zip'
```